# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LogicParser' with nltk.LogicParser()

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm playing with examples from [Natural Language Processing with Python](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/ch10.html) and this line:

```
lp = nltk.LogicParser()
```

produces

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LogicParser'
```

error message. I imported several nltk modules and I can't figure out what is missing. Any clues?

Comment: I did Ctrl+F "LogicParser" and can't find anything.  Where did you get that code?

Comment: @Kevin You are right, I updated the link without checking, sorry. It is in the [older version](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/ch10.html) and in the printed book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've spotted the problem, but just in case: You are reading the first edition of the NLTK book, but evidently you have installed NLTK 3, which has many changes. Look at the current version of [chapter 10](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html) for the correct usage.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. New version of the book replaced `LogicParser` with `sem.Expression.fromstring`.

Comment: It was nicer and simpler nltk.LogicParser() than nltk.sem.Expression.fromstring . But this answer nailed the solution

Comment: @Fidel, write `LogicParser = nltk.sem.Expression.fromstring` and you can even skip the `nltk.` prefix!